# PHP Delete Directory that is not empty

Tags: php, directory

I know that you can remove a folder that is empty with rmdir. And I know you can clear a folder with the following three lines.

```
foreach($directory_path as $file) {
       unlink($file);
}
```

But what if one of the files is actually a sub directory. How would one get rid of that but in an infinite amount like the dual mirror effect. Is there any force delete directory in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This function will delete a directory recursively:

```
function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
        if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
        else unlink("$dir/$file");
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

This one too:

```
function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach($it as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) rmdir($file->getPathname());
        else unlink($file->getPathname());
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: Actually you can use RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS flag to avoid first if statement...

Comment: SKIP_DOTS doesn't exist in the doc, where did you find this?

Comment: SKIP_DOTS is referenced here : [FilesystemIterator documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/filesystemiterator.construct.php). It's herited from parent class `FilesystemIterator`.

Comment: The first function well return an error if the parameter is a correct path but does not exist

Answer (score 9):

From PHP [`rmdir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#98622) page:

```
<?php 
 function rrmdir($dir) { 
   if (is_dir($dir)) { 
     $objects = scandir($dir); 
     foreach ($objects as $object) { 
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object); 
       } 
     } 
     reset($objects); 
     rmdir($dir); 
   } 
 } 
?>
```

And

```
<?php 
function delTree($dir) { 
    $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK ); 
    foreach( $files as $file ){ 
        if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/' ) 
            delTree( $file ); 
        else 
            unlink( $file ); 
    } 

    if (is_dir($dir)) rmdir( $dir ); 

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 
 function rrmdir($dir) { 
   if (is_dir($dir)) { 
     $objects = scandir($dir); 
     foreach ($objects as $object) { 
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object); 
       } 
     } 
     reset($objects); 
     rmdir($dir); 
   } 
 } 
?>
```

from PHP's documentation